# Dynamic SQL and Setof Functions in PG

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, pg

I am researching if it is possible to dynamically create a view and then return all data from it, all in a single function. My goal is to create a single function that will return all data from a dynamically created view, upon execution of the function. I can do it in Oracle and SQL Server, but so far I am not sure if it is that simple in Postgres. If someone could show code samples, ideas or point me in the right direction, I would be super happy :)

I already know how to create a SETOF function or a dynamic SQL function, but getting both to work in a single program/function function is a challenge that I cannot overcome so far ...

Answer (score 0):

The returned content can be dynamic, the structure should be static.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx(OUT a int, OUT b int)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT i, i+1 FROM generate_series(1,3)');
END;
```

[PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql.html) is good, please, don't be afraid to read it. The plpgsql related pages need no more than two hours.